# A problem with productivity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two cranes discharge a merchant ship for **11 hours**. The second of them starts **5h after** the first. For how many **hours** each crane will discharge the ship **alone** if the time that first crane needs is **10% more** than the time that second crane needs?

I've done the following table:

**first crane**: 
 
alone: 1,1x 
 
for one hour (productivity): $\frac {1}{1,1x}$

**second crane**: 
 
alone: x 
 
for one hour (productivity): $\frac 1x$

I can't write an equation, and I would be very grateful if you help me.

Comment: First thing to do is to identify some unknowns and give them names. Not good enough to just start writing down equations with X's and y's – you have to tell the reader what all those letters stand for! So: let $x$ be the number of hours the first crane needs, let $y$ be the number of hours the second crane needs. Now maybe you can start writing equations.

Comment: Since there are two cranes and only one ship, I assume the final part of the question should read "...  if the time that first *crane* needs is 10% more than the time that second *crane* needs ?"

Comment: @gandalf61, sorry my fault!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that crane one does $1/1.1$ units of productivity per hour, and crane two does $1$ unit of productivity per hour.

$1/1.1*11+1*6 = 16$. This is the total number of units of productivity required to discharge the boat. (Worked out from knowing crane 1 works 11 hours on the job, crane 2 works 6 on the job).

Let's find how many hours it takes for crane 1 on its own to do the job.
It takes $16/(1/1.1) = 17.6$ hours to do it.

For crane 2:
It takes $16$ hours to do it.

Comment: 1st sentence = "Crane 1 takes 10% longer to discharge boat on its own than Crane 2" = "Crane 1 works 10% slower than Crane 2"

Comment: The answers are 16 h and 17 h and 36 min.

Comment: small error forgive

Answer (score 1):

For me, I would always write down an equation "v = st" first where the v stands for speed or productivity,
t stands for time and s stands for distance traveled or numbers of things u have done.

Write s = 1 in this question.
First, let v_1 be productivity of the first one and v_2 be the productivity of the second one. From
"Two cranes discharge a merchant ship for 11 hours. The second of them starts 5h after the first.",
we have 11v_1 + 6v_2 = 1

From  "the time that first ship needs is 10% more than the time that second ship needs", (I guess what you mean is replacing ship by crane),
we see 1/(v_1) = 1.1/(v_2)

With these two equation, you can solve v_1 and v_2 respectively and solve the require time by v = st